# Verify multivalue with foreach

Tags: php, laravel

I have a column in the table 'games' with the value '1,2,3,4'

I would now like to analyze these IDs in the 'console' table, To check which console it is.
Just do not understand why, I only check the first value.

For example if I use the code below, It only displays: "PS4" and not "PS4 XONE PC".

```
$games = \DB::table('games')
    ->where('id', '=', $info_games->id_game)
    ->get();
foreach ($games as $row) {
    $cons =  \DB::table('console')
        ->where('id', '=', $row->console)
        ->get();
}
```

blade:

```
@foreach ($cons as $row)
 {{ $row->abb_cat }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: what's the problem here?

Comment: I have in the column id '1,2,3', Because he checks me in the "console" table, only the first id?

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
$games = \DB::table('games')
    ->where('id', '=', $info_games->id_game)
    ->get();
```

You get *one* game, with id = `$info_games->id_game`. So when you do the foreach loop, it's only going to loop one time, for that one game.

Now, that game has a `console` property with a value of `'1,2,3,4'`. In this code:

```
foreach ($games as $row) {
    $cons =  \DB::table('console')
        ->where('id', '=', $row->console)
        ->get();
}
```

When you refer to `$row->console`, you're going to get that value `1,2,3,4`. That value will be converted to an integer to be used to look up an id in the console table. Because `(int) '1,2,3,4'` is `1`, You only get one record back.

You can get them all by exploding the `console` value and using that array with `whereIn`.

```
$consoles = explode($games->first()->console);

$cons =  \DB::table('console')
    ->whereIn('id', $consoles)
    ->get();
```

---

What would be better is to normalize your database properly and build a many-to-many relationship between games and consoles.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are iterating through `$games` twice: the first time in your php file, and the second in your blade. When you do it in the script, `$cons` is being overwritten on every iteration. You would like to save them.

```
$list = [];

foreach ($games as $row) {
    $cons =  \DB::table('console')
        ->where('id', '=', $row->console)
        ->get();
    array_push($list, $cons);
}
```

Then pass `$list` to your blade.

```
@foreach ($list as $cons)
 {{ $cons->abb_cat }}
@endforeach
```